# Phalcon, Models, How to Action_on cascade set null?

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm using phalcon, and I'm trying to make the action on cascade set null all values.
Now I have this:

```
$this->hasOne("folder_id", "Common\Models\Folder", "id", array(
            'alias' => 'Folder',
            'foreignKey' => array(
                'action' => Relation::ACTION_CASCADE
            )
        ));
```

But that will delete the rows, I just want to set null, not delete.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible via Phalcon but, have you tried adding `"allowNulls" => true` to the `foreignKey` array? Otherwise you will have to change this in your database table relation.

Comment: You should post an answer for future users who come across this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done via Phalcon. I had to change my db table relation.